# Complicated sticky footer and 100% content height

Tags: css, layout, position, sticky-footer

I'm trying to stretch content div to 100% height:

http://new.art-frame.spb.ru/catalog

content DIV:

```
<div id="rt-transition">...</div>
```

footer:

```
<footer id="rt-footer-surround">...</footer>
```

The problem is, I can't change html layout, only CSS.

(the best way is to use Firebug/Chrome inspector to see what's all about)

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    min-width: 100px !important;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `height` of the `html` to `100%` instead of `auto`. Then, play around with the CSS of all the elements inside to make it fit. If there is excess overflow, use

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

To solve the problem, although this won't allow for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
min-height: 720px;
```

on your rt-main

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this would work. `min-height` in pixels doesn't respond well dynamically - have you changed the height of the browser?